# Retrieve object data with Forge Viewer (nested Families)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use forge-Viewer with dashboards to analyze the data within the model. For that, I am using the getAllLeafComponent() method expressed in the Forge Tutorials: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/panel?id=enumerate-leaf-nodes.

Nevertheless, I am having some trouble with this method, because it will not recognize objects that have children (i.e. Revit Families with nested items).

[Element with nested item (space of operation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QD4gR.png)

In the attached image, the green tetrahedron represents the transformer space of operation, and it is a nested item inside the transformer, so with the getAllLeafComponent() method I am unable to retrieve the transformer data, which is the important one; as this method does not recognize the transformer as a leaf, but rather as a parent element, which indeed it is, but it is also a model object, not a category or a family symbol.

Has anyone comes up with the same problem and/or with a way to solve it?

It is of uttermost importance for my Forge application, otherwise, I would not have reliable model information to analyze it.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The Model Derivative service uses a specific, "reasonable" logic for each individual input file format to decide how granular it should go when building the logical hierarchy for the viewer. In case of Revit designs, the processing stops at the instance level, in other words, family instances are always output as leaf nodes, even if their families have some nested elements. For example, doors are always output as the smallest selectable elements, and you cannot select just the door knob. I'm afraid the same applies to your space of operation nested within the transformer family.

If you need to extract information that the Model Derivative service does not provide, you could consider using the [Design Automation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/overview/) service instead. This service lets you execute your custom Revit (or AutoCAD, or Inventor, or 3ds Max) plugin on our servers, creating, modifying, or analyzing designs in any way you need, remotely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @PetrBroz. Nevertheless, I guess that de Model Derivative API is not following that logic with this model. I am able to select separately the space of operation, and when I select the transformer it includes the space of operation; and it is not including the transformer inside the leaf nodes, as it has a child and, therefore, tree.GetChildCounts() is not equal to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I probably misunderstood your question then. So, your issue is that there's important metadata on a "transformer" object, but since this object is not a leaf (it has the "space of operation" nested within it), it's not included by the `getAllLeafComponents` method, is that correct? In that case I'd suggest that you modify the logic that collects the IDs of objects you want to query for metadata. Instead of just collecting leaf nodes, you can select specific objects based on some specific metadata.

Comment: In other words, in our tutorials we collect leaf nodes because those *typically* contain more important metadata. But of course, every design and use case is different, and you're free to query the metadata from any objects you want.

Comment: Wanted to say that I’ve had this same issue. Nested families in Revit are treated as the leaf nodes when translated, thus making it difficult to consistently get at metadata stored on the instance level element.

There really needs to be some more detail about granularity put into the node logic. I thought this would be found in the InstanceTree’s getNodeType method, but it seems to be broken as it only returns 0 for every object